# asp.net autocomplete and IE autocomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

So I have an asp:AutoCompleteExtender which works fine but is there a way to actually turn off the build in autocomplete from Internet Explorer because when I input text into a textbox both autocompletes show up, one on top of the other.

I just want to turn off the build in IE autocomplete for the one textbox not the whole system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable IE's auto-complete with the following code:

```
<INPUT NAME="Foo" AUTOCOMPLETE="off" />
```

More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtname" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

or

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtname" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="none"></asp:TextBox>
```